# Bootstrap modal dialog center image in body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center an image (both horizontally and vertically) in a modal dialog body.  I have tried every permutation of everything I know.  top / left = 50%, margin 0 auto, class=center-block... Read through the bootstrap documentation and I am stumped.  Here is my html... Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<div id="processing" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 350px">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="panel-heading modal-header dialog-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Please Wait...</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 230px;">
                <img src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Thank you Chun for the response, but it did not achieve the desired results.
Here is a link to 2 images.  One is the result from Chun's suggestion, the other is a manipulated image to exhibit my desired result.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kj2no3ovgivjjt8/AAAarW9SjuBjYMWZPCUaKebua?dl=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**========= Updated Answer ==========**

I did see the image from your link going outside of your div container, here's what needs to be done in order to fix this problem. Forget all the code provided previously, let's start over. Giving a `position:relative;` to `.modal-body` will avoid the image of going outside of the container, here's an example:

```
.modal-body {
    position:relative; /* This avoids whatever it's absolute inside of it to go off the container */
    height: 250px; /* let's imagine that your login box height is 250px . This height needs to be added, otherwise .img-responsive will be like "Oh no, I need to be vertically aligned?! but from which value I need to be aligned??" */
}
```

Then, create your centered login image by styling the class `.img-responsive`

```
.img-responsive {
    width:50px; /* This value will depend on what size you want for your loading image, let's say it's 50px */
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-25px; /* This needs to be half of the height */
    margin-left:-25px; /* This needs to be half of the width */
}
```

**[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/or1bm4Lt/2/)**

Comment: Thank you but this didn't quite get me there.  Here is a link to the screen captures. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kj2no3ovgivjjt8/AAAarW9SjuBjYMWZPCUaKebua?dl=0

Comment: I suggest not override bootstrap classes, but just inherit their properties... E.g.: `.img-resp-my { .img-responsive; [!YOUR CUSTOM CSS HERE!]; } .modal-body-my { .modal-body; [!YOUR CUSTOM CSS HERE!]; }`.

Comment: CORRECTION: To use a syntax according to the last comment you need a library called LESS ( http://lesscss.org/ ).

Answer (score 13):

This will center the image inside of the modal.

```
.modal-body > .img-responsive {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Not working. But this is works by adding a class : .img-center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

Comment: This working in the bootstrap modal body completely

Answer (score 10):

It must be working by adding more class :

```
<style>
  .img-center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Nice to see the <script> tags included in the answer, Truly "class'y" :)

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this issue just add bootstrap's `img-fluid` class.

So the code will look like this,

```
<div id="processing" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 350px">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="panel-heading modal-header dialog-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Please Wait...</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 230px;">
                <img src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="img-fluid" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```